# How to use CASE in JOIN statement to join two tables based on condition?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, case

I have three tables : **email**, **customer_new** and **customers_old**.
Now in **email** table there is a field called **type** that contains **0** or **1**.
So if **type** contains **0** then I want to fetch **name** column from **customer_new** table else from **customer_old** table.

For this I made below mysql query :

```
SELECT email.*, 
CASE email.`type`
    WHEN 1 THEN customer_old.name
    ELSE customer_new.name
END AS customer_name 
LEFT JOIN 
CASE email.`type`
    WHEN 0 THEN customer_new ON email.customer_id = customer_new.id
    ELSE customer_old ON email.customer_id = customer_old.id
END
FROM email
```

Now when I run this query mysql always throws error.
Can somebody solve my issue regarding join two table through CASE statement based on condition ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of using it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below query.

```
SELECT email . * , IF( email.type = '1', customer_old.name, customer_new.name ) AS name 
FROM email
LEFT JOIN customer_old ON ( customer_old.id = email.customer_id ) 
LEFT JOIN customer_new ON ( customer_new.id = email.customer_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select email.*,
CASE email.type 
  when 1 then customer_old.name
  else customer_new.name 
  end as filteredname
from email,customer_new,customer_old 
where 
  customer_new.id=email.id 
and 
  customer_old.id=email.id;
```

You may use left join to optimize the execution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative,

```
SELECT * FROM email 
LEFT JOIN customer_new AS customer ON email.customer_id = customer.id 
WHERE email.type = 0

UNION

SELECT * FROM email 
LEFT JOIN customer_old AS customer ON email.customer_id = customer.id 
WHERE email.type = 1
```